# Create Java Utility Function to Convert Unsigned Char Array to String

Tags: swig

SWIG converts the below unsigned char array ("id") to short[].  On the C side, the id attribute of the sender_id_t_ struct is a pointer to an array that contains alphanumeric data like "TEST123-E". I suppose you could loop over short[] (sender_id_t_.getId()) and cast each element to a char and concatenate to build a Java String.  I'm wondering if their is a better and simpler way of handling this situation?

**C Header File:**

```
#define SAMPLE_ID_SIZE_V1 32
#define SAMPLE_ID_SIZE SAMPLE_ID_SIZE_V1

typedef unsigned char sample_id_v1_t[SAMPLE_ID_SIZE];
typedef sample_id_v1_t sample_id_t;

struct sample_sender_id_t_ {
    sample_id_t           id;
    uint32_t              idx;
};
typedef struct sample_sender_id_t_ sample_sender_id_t;
```

**SWIG.i:**

```
%rename (Sample) sender_id_t_;
struct sender_id_t_ {
    unsigned char id_v1_t[32]      id;
    uint32_t   phy_idx;
};
```

**Exception:**

```
 [exec] test_wrap.c: In function `TestJNI_Sample_1id_1set':
 [exec] test_wrap.c:826: error: cast specifies array type
 [exec] test_wrap.c:829: error: incompatible types in assignment
 [exec] test_wrap.c:832: error: `jarr2' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets treated as an array of `short` because of the `unsigned` of the type, which makes the largest value too large to fit in a (signed) `byte` or `char`. If you want to force it to be treated a `String` you can use `%apply` to use the normal `String` typemaps, something like:

```
%module test

%rename (Sample) sender_id_t_;
%apply char * { unsigned char id[32] };

struct sender_id_t_ {
    unsigned char id[32];
    uint32_t   phy_idx;
};
```

(I had to fix some syntax in your `struct`, that was a bit odd).

Comment: The struct is a bit odd to me in the C header file (included that above now).  I may not have the correct SWIG.i definition for the sender_id_t_ struct.  When I try the %apply char * as you suggested I get a type compatibility error, full stack is above too. Do you know the proper SWIG.i struct based on the C header file I provided?

Comment: @c12 - make the contents of the `struct` in SWIG interface match the headerfile - that error is because `id` in SWIG.i is very different to the headerfile I suspect.